# Why reactor doOnError is not getting executed in this case?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I am not able to figure out why first `doOnError` code is not getting executed in this example, I have method that call REST service using `WebClient`, and return response as `InputStream`:

```java
public InputStream loadAsStream() throws IOException {
    PipedOutputStream osPipe = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream isPipe = new PipedInputStream(osPipe);
    Mono<ClientResponse> mono = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8089/")
            .build()
            .get()
            .uri("/loadData")
            .accept(MediaType.ALL)
            .exchange()
            .doOnError(e -> LOG.error("first doOnError: ", e));
    Flux<DataBuffer> flux = DataBufferUtils.write(mono.flatMapMany(response -> response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())), osPipe);
    flux.doOnError(e -> LOG.error("second doOnError: ", e))
            .doFinally(s -> LOG.debug("finally"))
            .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer());
    return isPipe;
}
```

InputStream will be used later to deserialize POJO using ObjectMapper:

```java
try (InputStream inputStream = loadService.loadAsStream()) {
      pojo = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, SimplePojo.class);
} catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

For example, if service is not available and REST call failed with error then both first `doOnError` and second `doOnError` are getting executed, but if I have exception during deserialization (inside `objectMapper.readValue`) then only second `doOnError` is getting executed, could you please help me understand why ?

Comment: What is your desired behavior? Error handling on reactive streams is not an exit condition. You'll need to use `onErrorStop` or `onErrorReturn` to have these streams terminate.

Comment: I don't want terminate streams, I just want understand why first doOnError is not executed when error happened inside 
`objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, SimplePojo.class)`

Comment: Your code is missing the point where the deserialization happens in the flow. Most probably it is happening AFTER the first doOnError, that's why that is not triggered. Error signal is not propagated backwards.